# Big search and replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named *news* with a column *content* of type *text*. This table contains more than 50000 records.

The text of the *content* column may contains several links that look like that http://www.domain.com/news/voir/ID/title I want to replace the **domain.com** in all these links with **newdomain.com**

What is the most efficient solution to do this ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend

```
UPDATE news SET content = REPLACE(content, 'http://www.domain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

to avoid hitting possibly LOTS of flase positives ... think of a news article saying "An outage today hit domain.com, as the ISP blah blah" ... you wouldn't want to replace that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
UPDATE news
SET content = replace(content,'domain.com','newdomain.com');
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql replace() to the rescue!

`UPDATE news SET content = REPLACE(content, 'domain.com', 'newdomain.com');`